# show webfroms in mvc _layout page mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

is there a way to load webforms in mvc _layout page like views render in _layout page there is a crystal report in my webform page I want to render it in mvc shared view _layout page is it possible ?

Comment: This reference may help you: [Use webforms view with Razor layout](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3). Even it written for MVC 3, it should also works in MVC 5.

Comment: Not working getting error on viewbag and html.partialview

Comment: Can you provide code that currently doesn't work? Is that `ViewBag` content has null value? Without example code I can't analyze where & why the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

[it says not contain defination for partial missing refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4dOk.png)

[and one here on html.raw missing refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaoJI.png)